# Insert elements before/after certain element in array

Tags: ruby

I have method `header_components` and I want to create method `add_header_components` with behaviour like this:

```
add_header_components << :buttons, after: :logo #=> [:logo, :buttons, :user_name]
header_components #=> [:logo, :user_name]
```

This is what I try:

```
  # this method just return the array
  def header_components
    [:logo, :user]
  end

  def add_header_components(name, *args)
    h = header_components
    options = args.extract_options!
    if options.keys.include?(:after)
      index = header_components.index(options[:after])
      h = header_components.insert(index+1, name.to_s)
    elsif options.keys.include?(:before)
      index = header_components.index(options[:before])
      h = header_components.insert(index, name.to_s)
    end
    h
  end
```

this method works but I want pass more than one `name` parameter to method.

#### Another question:

If there any way to get the same array with this syntax:

```
header_components << :buttons, :search, after: :logo
```

Comment: I don't think `add_header_components << :buttons, after: :logo` works. Did you mean `add_header_components :buttons, after: :logo` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `header_components` is behaving like a variable, why not make it one? As for adding multiple headers at once, you can use the splat/double splat syntax:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :header_components
  def initialize
    @header_components = ['logo', 'user']
  end

  def add_header_components(*headers, **options)
    if options.keys.include?(:after)
      index = @header_components.index(options[:after])
      @header_components.insert(index+1, *headers)
    elsif options.keys.include?(:before)
      index = @header_components.index(options[:before])
      @header_components.insert(index, *headers)
    else
      # I guess this should by default append all headers to the list?
     @header_components.concat headers
    end
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.header_components # => ['logo', 'user']
f.add_header_components('hello', 'world', after: 'logo')
f.header_components # => ['logo', 'hello', 'world', 'user']
```